# Need help in Xamarin Test Cloud Automation

Tags: unit-testing, calabash, xamarin-test-cloud

In Xamrain test cloud both Xamarin.UITest/Calabash is unit testing ? Can't i write in calabash if my app is written with Xamarin as i am not more comfortable with c# ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can write your test cases in calabash though your app is written in Xamarin. 
Follow this link you might get your answer in Xamrin.iOS section
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/introduction-to-calabash/